# typescript lose type when creating the object using nested array.map

Tags: typescript

I'm having some issue with typescript autocomplete, when I try to create an object with nested `array.map` the autocomplete stop working. Here is an example of the issue:

```
type Test = {
  title: string;
  questions: {
    title: string;
    options: {
      title: string;
      description?: string;
    }[];
  }[];
};

const notWorkingItem: Test = {
  title: "",
  questions: [].map(() => ({
    title: "",
    options: myArray.map(() => ({
      title: "auto complete not working"
    }))
  }))
};

const workingItem: Test = {
  title: "",
  questions: myArray.map(() => ({
    title: "",
    options: [
      {
        title: "auto complete working"
      }
    ]
  }))
};
```

here you can see the code:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/blissful-fire-u5rghc

if you click control+space to show the autocomplete you will see this:
[image]
[image]

what am I doing wrong? is this a typescript limitation?

many thanks